# What is the Chinese origin of “kai shao”

Tags: etymology

I’ve seen people [explain the custom](http://cheftonio.blogspot.com/2013/04/modern-kai-shao.html?m=1) of relatives and friends to introduce potential future partners, and referring to it in English as “kai shao”.

What is the Chinese origin for this? The closest I can think of is 介绍 (to introduce), but the pinyin (jièshào) is pretty far off. The Cantonese pronunciation (gaai siu) is closer but still doesn’t sound right.

Comment: In Mandarin this is more likely to be referred to as 相亲 but 介绍 is definitely a big part of the “blind-date” process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just 介紹.

- Following the blog post, it mentions *Philippines* culture.
- Looking up [languages of the Philippines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_the_Philippines#Hokkien), we get *Hokkien* as a major Chinese topolect.
- Looking up [介紹 in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8B%E7%B4%B9#Chinese), the *Hokkien* Romanisation is **kài-siāu**.

The blog post spelling it as "kai shao" is just not following a particular topolect's Romanisation, but just spelling it out by ear.

Comment: What a great answer  It was the Hokkien sound!

Answer (score 0):

它是南方的方言。我认为直接用jie shao会更多人看懂。方言很少在国外使用。